# Consulta de Mysql con MIN() mezcla los campos de distintos registros agrupando campos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tambien tengo esta tabla donde se guardan las los presupuestos o cotizaciones , t_coti, en esta tabla guardo el ID de los Medicamentos y la fecha en la que se crea el presupuesto, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la siguiente tabla tt_cot_pro, en esta tabla tengo precio de medicamento, ID del proveedor que vende a ese precio y la fecha en la que nos venden a ese precio.

[image: Parte de la tabla tt_cot_pro]

El medicamento 12067, tiene dos pedidos de cotización, El 21 y el 22

1. la Cotizacion 22 tiene una sola oferta de del Proveedor 3 (tercera columna) a un precio de $100 en la 4 columna
2. la cotizacion 21 tiene 3 ofertas, proveedor 1,2 y 3

La consulta que no puedo sacar es: el minimo precio de cada cotización.
que tendria que ser
precio 450 del proveedor 1 con fecha 2022-04-11
precio 100 del proveedor 3 con fecha 2022-04-13

en la siguiente consulta de MySQL

```
**SELECT min(tt.pre),tt.Id_cot,tt.id_pro, DATE_FORMAT(tt.fec, '%d-%m-%Y') , c.id_med
from tt_cot_pro tt inner join t_coti c on c.id=tt.id_cot
 where c.id_med=12067
group by 2**
```

me tira el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que está MAL, porque el precio de 450 no es del proveedor 2 sino del proveedor 1 y esa no es la fecha.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL?

Comment: en mi PC local tengo la versión: 7.4.7

Answer (score 3):

`Mysql` en algunas versiones/configuraciones trabaja el `group by` sin respetar el estándar `SQL-92` y permite indicar columnas  sin función de agregación y sin agrupar, el resultado es válido en la columna agrupada y en la función de agregación, pero el resto de las columnas no tienen nada que ver con estos datos. Para los que estamos acostumbrados al `group by` tradicional esto es una aberración, que puede reconfigurarse ([ver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)) para forzar el estándar más actual. De todas formas, para obtener el precio mínimo por medicamento y cotización se hace esto:

```
SELECT tt.id_cot, 
       c.id_med,
       min(tt.pre) as min_pre
       from tt_cot_pro tt 
       inner join t_coti c 
            on c.id=tt.id_cot
       group by tt.id_cot, c.id_med
```

Si además quisieras el resto de los datos de la cotización, puedes usar lo anterior como subconsulta:

```
SELECT tt.Id_cot,
       tt.id_pro, 
       DATE_FORMAT(tt.fec, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha,
       m.id_med,
       m.min_pre
       from tt_cot_pro tt
       inner join (
             SELECT tt2.id_cot, 
                    c.id_med,
                    min(tt2.pre) as min_pre
                    from tt_cot_pro tt2 
                    inner join t_coti c 
                          on c.id=tt2.id_cot
                    group by tt2.id_cot, c.id_med
       ) m
       on tt.id_cot = m.id_cot
       where m.id_med=12067
```

Comment: Esta consulta no funciona, porque me tira 4 registros y solo tiene que tirar dos

Comment: ¿Cuál regla del SQL92 no respeta MySQL? Por favor indica inciso y número de  regla.

Comment: @LuisDarrull, intenté ayudarte dándote una explicación conceptual de como resolverlo, para que en todo caso entendieras dónde está el problema y tú puedas resolverlo, tu comentario no me ayuda a ayudarte ¿podrías ser más específico? ¿Que datos muestran dichas filas?

Comment: @Sal, el enlace que dejé  apunta a la documentación de `mysql` que explica  esta situación, creo que no agrega mucho documentar el estándar. De todas formas, la definición del `group by` está en la sección `7.7  <group by clause>` pero mucho antes, cuando se explica que es una tabla se dice : `A group is a multiset of rows in which all values of the grouping column or columns are equal if a <group by clause> is specified`

Answer (score 1):

Fallo de concepto, el *min* es para saber cual es el mínimo pero solo eso prueba un enfoque diferente:

### Código:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
precio INT NOT NULL,
producto VARCHAR(30),
proveedor VARCHAR(50),
date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO tabla (precio,producto,proveedor) values 
(500,'producto 1','prooveedor 1'),
(200,'producto 1','prooveedor 2'),
(300,'producto 1','prooveedor 3'),
(400,'producto 1','prooveedor 4');
```

### Consulta:

```
select * from tabla
where precio=(select min(precio) from tabla)
```

[Ejemplo funcional](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s5tG2LcCnWA19KpChwsq2Q/2)

Comment: Este Ejemplo no me sirve porque no hay grupos, me sería más útil si a las vez tengo producto 2 y necesito el minimo de cada producto y los detalles o nombres de los produtos están en otra tabla

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.id_cot,MIN(t1.min_pre) min_pre1, t2.id_pro, t2.fec, p.nom
From
            (SELECT tt2.id,tt2.id_pro,min(tt2.pre) as min_pre, tt2.id_cot
                    from tt_cot_pro tt2 
                    group by tt2.id_cot,tt2.id_pro) t1
                    
            inner join tt_cot_pro t2 on t2.id = t1.id
            inner join t_coti c on t1.id_cot=c.id
            inner join 
            (select m.id, m.nom from t_med m where m.id="12067") m on m.id = c.id_med
            inner join t_pro p on t1.id_pro=p.id
    
group by 1
```

Comment: Procura agregar más detalles a tu respuesta: si bien te pudo haber sido útil, necesitas detallarla para que otros usuarios en un futuro puedan comprender _por qué_ funciona esto. Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla. No olvides además aceptar la respuesta que más te ha sido de provecho.